# How can I select a dropdown option in excel from my html select tag using python?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I am trying to create a new row in an excel spreadsheet using a html form, python and flask.
The dropdown cell in excel is protected to restrict the values that can be selected. The protected cell is in column 3
Based off the value selected in the excel spreadsheet, the next column (column 4) auto fills the techs user id based off the tech selected. (This is to handle a function I have to count the total amount of reviews they have).

When I submit the form, I get this error:

```
2023-05-10 17:47:12,501: gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

I added the '' in the row data to skip over that column for the time being as I'm just trying to troubleshoot the protected column.

```
if request.method == "POST":
        review_date = request.form['review_date']
        tech_name = request.form['select_installer']
        account_id = request.form['account_id']
        
        row_data = [review_date, '', tech_name, account_id]
        gReviewWorksheet.append_row(row_data)
```

```
<form method="POST">
  <div id="review-modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content modal-card modal-animate" style="max-width:600px">
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-section">
          <label for="review-date">Review Date:</label>
          <input type="month" id="review-date" name="review_date">
          <label for="tech-select">Choose tech(s):</label>
          <select multiple id="tech-select" name="select_installer">
            {% for installers in all_installers %}
            <option value="{{ installers['l_name'] + ',' + ' ' + installers['f_name'] }}">{{ installers['f_name'] + ' ' + installers['l_name'] }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <label for="account-id">Account ID:</label>
          <input type="text" id="account-id" name="account_id">
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="submit" name="review_submit" id="review-submit" class="modal-button-submit">Submit</button>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('review-modal').style.display='none'" type="button"
            class="modal-button-close">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So basically, the user selects a month, selects a tech and inputs an account ID.
When the user submits, the month needs to append to column 1, the year needs to append to column 2, the option selected needs to match the techs name in the excel dropdown to populate there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. if someone has an easier way, feel free to post your answer!

```
if request.method == "POST":
    review_date = request.form.get("review_date")
    selected_tech = request.form.get("selected_tech")
    review_account_id = request.form.get("account_id")
    if review_date and selected_tech and review_account_id:
        parsed_date = datetime.strptime(review_date, "%Y-%m")
        month = parsed_date.strftime("%-m")
        year = parsed_date.strftime("%Y")
        # Get the last row in the worksheet
        last_row = len(gReviewWorksheet.get_all_values()) + 1
        # Append data to the certain row
        gReviewWorksheet.update(f"A{last_row}", month)
        gReviewWorksheet.update(f"B{last_row}", year)
        gReviewWorksheet.update(f"C{last_row}", selected_tech)
        gReviewWorksheet.update(f"F{last_row}", review_account_id)
```